# Driving Inductive Load with MOSFET: N-Channel vs. P-Channel

Tags: pwm, nmos, inductive, pmos

**Problem**

I am driving an inductive load from a microcontroller using a MOSFET. I have a current sense resistor in series with the load. I don't have much experience with transistors (should have paid more attention in school!) so I'm trying to implement the circuit using both an NMOS and PMOS transistor.

The problem is that the PMOS circuit is behaving as expected while the NMOS circuit is behaving erratically. I would like to know what is causing the differences.

**P-Channel MOSFET**

Here is the circuit with the P-Channel MOSFET. V1 is a 32 kHz PWM signal with 50% duty cycle. Since the current sense resistor is connected to ground, I can easily measure the voltage using a non-inverting amplifier.

[image]

As the simulation results, the circuit does exactly what you expect; the voltage across the current-sense resistor tracks perfectly linearly with current in the inductor.

[image: P-Channel graph]

**N-Channel MOSFET**

Here is the circuit with the N-Channel MOSFET. V1 is a 32 kHz PWM signal with 50% duty cycle. The current sense resistor isn't connected to ground so I use a differential amplifier to measure the voltage across it.

[image: N-Channel]

[**LT1677 data sheet**](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1677fa.pdf)

The behavior of this circuit is not what I expect it to be. The current through the inductor is much lower than the PMOS topology and V_SENSE is a mess.

[image: N-Channel Graph]

Here is a zoomed in version with the PWM signal V1 included (shown in RED).

[image]

**Questions**

1. <strike>Why is the current through the inductor in the NMOS circuit half that of the PMOS circuit?</strike> **EDIT: Fixed schematic, swapped PMOS drain & source**
2. Why is the differential amplifier not working as expected? I am guessing that R2 is somehow coupling the op-amp inputs to ground. Since R_SENSE is "floating", this is causing issues.
3. <strike>You can't tell from my graphs but in the NMOS circuit, the current through the inductor is much noisier than the PMOS circuit.</strike> **EDIT: Fixed schematic, swapped PMOS drain & source**

Comment: In your first circuit you have P-MOSFET connected wrongly. You have swapped drain with source.

Comment: Get rid of the diff-amp by putting the 0.1R between the N-MOS and ground. Just keep in mind the voltage offset and make sure your gate drive is adequate.

Comment: @Chupacabras DOH! That tells me it's time get some rest.

Comment: @Daniel Between the source and ground? That doesn't make sense to me since when the transistor is off, no current would flow through R_SENSE.

Comment: See :-) ........ later ... going out.

Comment: Source to ground OK while FET is on as long as you sample then. I_inductor before/after switching is continuous.

Comment: As Bruce says - you are exceeding LT1677 Vcm - which may be issue depending on how good the simulation is. Opamp Vcm is just inside rails (varies with temperature. You can do as Bruce says or (poor but workable) divide Vin in each leg by a small amount to bring inside CM range. Say 10k to ground from each OA input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'noise' you see on the sense output is caused by the the op amp's inputs exceeding their common mode range. But how can this happen when the op amp has rail-to-rail inputs?

When the the FET is turned off, the inductor tries to maintain any current going through it. To do this it generates a voltage that goes *above* the power supply voltage. D1 limits this voltage rise to about 0.6V, while recirculating current through the inductor. During this time the op amp's inputs are driven to about +12.6V, 0.6V above V+ (which is very bad because they are rated for an *absolute maximum* of 0.3V beyond the supply rails).

To solve this problem, relocate the sense resistor to the other end of the inductor. Now the inputs will stay just below 12V, and the op amp should work properly.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for the explanation as well.